# React won't understand the image sent to it by flask

Tags: reactjs

Right now, i'm trying to get my flask backend to send an image stored as a numpy array to my react frontend, and i'm not sure how. React is unable to display an image based off of an array, and when I save the numpy array as a file, and send that file to react as such:

```
return send_file("./uploadfolder/imageofchoice.png")
```

React receives the file, but is unable to display it, since it doesn't recognize the encoding or something. Does anyone know how to work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: i want to ask something different : should it be a more of a html issue? i mean if i did `x(){return send_file("./uploadfolder/imageofchoice.png")}` then save the return to someplace like `r = x()` and finally in my html `<img src=r>` . Shouldn't it work?

Comment: I've tried displaying the data in <img src = this.state.file/> (same as you said basically) but it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: ok. why dont you `<img src="./uploadfolder/imageofchoice.png">` i guess if u know location, u don't need a function then.

Comment: also make sure u are really uploading png to be specific [ or jpeg,png,.. (somehting else ]   `<input type="file" accept=".mp4,.flv">`

Comment: `<img src = this.state.file>` can u make sure the type of `this.state.file` is really png or not? i mean make a type check with if - if the file is image or not then display it.

Comment: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/uploader/how-to/check-the-mime-type-of-file-before-upload-it/ here is code for type checking of your file

Comment: I think the problem may be that react can't access files outside of its own app. However, I can't put the file in the main directory, since the states will hot reload when a file is saved.

Comment: Ok, it returns string when i do typeof

Comment: i don't know a way about accessing file outside apps own directory, i guess you have to search other ways